# How to use .split() with a discord bot python

Tags: python, split, discord

This is my code:

```
    @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    global warn
    if message.author == bot.user:
        return
    x = message.content
    if x.upper() == 'SPAM':
        if warn == 2:
            y1, y2 = message.author.split("#")
            user = discord.utils.get(bot.users, name=y1, discriminator=y2)
            if user is None:
                print("User not found")
            else:
                await message.channel.send(f"!mute {user.mention}")
                warn = 0
        user = "<@&1014487310361968640>"
        await message.channel.send(user)
        warn += 1
```

It's supposed to mention @staff for 2 times then mute the user but instead it gets stuck on .split() function.

Answer (score 0):

[`message.author`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.author) is an instance of either [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) or [`discord.abc.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User), not a string. For `split` to work, it has to be converted to a string first:

```py
y1, y2 = str(message.author).split("#")
```

Note that both classes also have [`name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.name) and [`discriminator`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.abc.User.discriminator) attributes that you could use instead:

```py
y1, y2 = message.author.name, message.author.discriminator
```